# Length of array in jade undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, template-engine

I have code i want to show count of tables in restaurant My code is:

```
#{restaurant.tables.length}
```

But it not works for me and error me "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".how can i solve this?

tables is array i fetch from mongodb collection.

i use mongoosejs "findOne" method, and my restaurant schema is :

```
 var restuarantSchema = new Schema({
    name : String,
    details : String,
    owner : String,
    categories : {
       name : String
    },
    users : [],
    tabels: [{
        title: String
    }]
});
```

Comment: You really should search before asking. There are tons of questions with the _same error_ in the javascript tag.

Comment: can you show how you fetch `tables`?

Comment: i updated post and i added my schema

Comment: Guys i did really bad mistake here is mismatch in my schema i wrote "tabels" as "tables"
also i can say we have length of array in jade files. now my code works fine

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a typo in your `#{restaurant.tables.length}` it should be `tabels`